# Auto Include a class in a C# file being served from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am making a simple api without any ide. I have three files in my website's root.

default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" src="default.cs" inherits="foo" %>
```

default.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using TechStreet;

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public class foo : Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Response.Write(Database.Query("SELECT * FROM users", new String[0]));
    }
}
```

Database.class.cs

```
namespace TechStreet {
    public class Database {
        public static string Query(string query, string[] parameters) {
            return "done";
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that loading default.aspx, it rightfully doesn't recognize the TechStreet namespace because I never tell them where the file is. If I understand this correctly then I need to compile both these files together or provide a reference to the database.dll when I compile default.cs. But I never compile default.cs. It gets compiled automatically when the page is first loaded.

Another solution is to compile the database.cs and put it in /bin/. But I will have to do this every time I make a change in the file.

So my question is, is there any way to "tell" default.cs to also auto compile and reference the database.cs when it compiles itself?

Comment: Have you tried storing your Database.class.cs in the App_Code directory?

Comment: I don't get it... Will all files mentioned above reside in the same dll when compiled (or are there any references to extarnal dll's?)?? If not, do this line, `Response.Write(Database.Query("SELECT * FROM users", new String[0]));`, really compile?

Comment: @schudel that was it! Thanks! If you can add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @haunstm yeah that file is still work in progress. I was stuck one level above it. I didn't really know where to put the code, compilation comes after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the Database.class.cs into the App_Code directory.